# How to Use two different users in bash scripting

Tags: bash

Hi everyone,
            I am writing a bash script on RedHat V5.1. In this script i have to run one command using dbAdmin and right after that i have to switch again to root user to run the other commands. Can anybody tell me how i can do this in bash scripting.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your script as root.Then in any part of code just do this:

```
su - dbadmin -c "command"
```

Replace command with whatever you want to run under dbadmin user.

This is exact way how redhat init scripts run services under specific users, eg. oracle DB

Comment: Yes I agree with @rkosegi you want to use the su -c option, if you use sudo the user must be built into your sudoers list since you're using a RedHat based distribution users are typically not in the sudoers list by default.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SUDO command to switch between root and your dbAdmin account.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=826935

http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Answer (score 1):

```
# command1 ; command2 ; sudo -u dbAdmin command3 ; command4 ; command5
```